# Trocar caracteres acentuados por não acentuados

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, acentuação

Há algum tipo de método de eu fazer um *replace* em caracteres com base no CASE do mesmo? Procuro algo assim:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = SUBSTRING(bar, "Ã","ã");
-- se o caracter for LOWER -> ã
-- se o caracter for UPPER -> Ã
```

Imaginem a tabela abaixo:

```
-------------------------
| id | nome             |
-------------------------
|  1 | Cão              |
|  2 | ALEMÃO           |
|  3 | jOÃO             |
-------------------------
```

Preciso que se transforme nisso

```
-------------------------
| id | nome             |
-------------------------
|  1 | Cao              | -> trocou "ã" por "a"
|  2 | ALEMAO           | -> trocou "Ã" por "A"
|  3 | jOAO             | -> trocou "Ã" por "A"
-------------------------
```

Comment: Você vai precisar criar uma function para isso, vê se tutorial aqui te ajuda: http://www.devmedia.com.br/funcao-para-retirar-acento/17293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o `COLLATE` para realizar isso, não sei se é o que quer ou se vai funcionar, a pergunta está genérica demais:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = (SELECT bar COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/Collate.sql).